# What would be the best way to create a GUI for selenium automation?

Tags: python, selenium, user-interface, tkinter

I am looking to turn my script which is written in python and uses selenium to automate tasks on a client’s website. I am looking to create a GUI that allows my client to run these automations on their site simply by interacting with the GUI. Im not sure if this is possible but the idea is that the client would just click a button on the interface which would then trigger the automation depending on the input selected. They want to be able to run these automations scripts on their own. I am trying to make it easy for them to interact with the automation script by building a GUI due to a lack of coding knowledge.

Comment: This question is off-topic since it is opinion based.

Comment: I have two projects you may want to look at for ideas.  Browsermator: https://www.browsermator.com and TheBrowserBots, which uses Browsermator as it's engine: https://www.thebrowserbots.com  Browsermator includes a file cloud to store/share "browsermation" files.  You can also view the source code at github (link at browsermator site)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would go with the easiest approach which to me would be using Jenkins as your UI.

[Jenkins](https://www.jenkins.io/doc/) is a CI/CD tool that helps us to trigger our automated tests, no matter which automation framework you are using you can integrate your tests there, but you can use this tool as a UI to trigger your tests suite.

If your client wants to run some tests he should be able to do it directly on Jenkins. You can make it as easy as you want, from a single button or as hard as having many options, is up to your needs.